# Are there any general methods available for transforming a BVP into an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any general methods available for transforming a 2nd order Boundary value problem such as

$F\left(x,y,\frac{\text{dy}}{\text{dx}},\frac{d^2y}{\text{dx}^2}\right)=0$

$y(a)=y_0$ and $y(b)=y_1$

into an initial value problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a certain class of BVP, the answer is yes according to [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2027566) article.